# Program Automation with Powershell

Tags: vb.net, powershell, automation

I've got a question as I can't seem to find any reference online.

I am trying to automate a data import tool for a client.  They spend roughly 1-3 hours per day downloading data and clicking buttons, waiting, and click.  They would like a script that will go through the data import tool and cycle through clicking buttons to import the data.

I have seen that there are options to SendKey for VB and PowerShell, but from my research, it looks like you need to know what the button is named in order to send the click (this makes sense logically to me).

Are there any resources out there to guide me in this endeavor?  As a non scripting guy, my google foo is failing me.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Send keys and scripted button clicking is always the last resort. First you should research the app and determine if it exposes an API that you can program against to do the import. Failing that, research what the import actually does. If it is just sticking data directly into a DB for instance you could just script that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on SendKeys if it can be avoided.  Have a look at the UIAutomation API in Windows.  Here is a [MSDN article on using it with PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx).